# Removed link from json file while generating json from Informatica

Tags: informatica, provisioning, informatica-cloud

I am creating JSON file from Informatica. What I did so far:

- 1. configure the basic entity in Informatica MDM hub
- 2. create a Base object in the provisioning tool

Then, I accessed the predefined URL by Informatica like
 `"server:port"/cmx/cs/"databaseid"/"baseobjectname"/id.json.`

By default, Informatica places the link attribute inside of the JSON file for parent/child/self if any

Is there any way we can remove the link attribute?

I am getting below output

```
{
  "link": [
    {
      "href": "serveraddress//1.json?depth=2",
      "rel": "children"
    },
    {
      "href": "serveraddress//1.json",
      "rel": "self"
    }
  ],
  "rowidObject": "2"
}
```

Expected:

```
{
  "rowidObject": "2"
}
```

Comment: it looks like a nested json. can you pick second part?

Comment: i want to remove link attribute which is created by default in any case in any json

Answer (score 0):

Finally i am able to solve this using the suppressLinks=true in the url call

http://:/cmx/cs//?q=''&depth=3&suppressLinks=true